# Why is XmlJavaTypeAdapter ignored in parent class

Tags: java, jaxb

I have class:

```
public class FooImpl extends Foo {

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(ListXmlAdapter.class)
    @Override
    public Map<String, List<String>> getList() {
        return super.getList();
    }
}
```

when I want to marshal this class then this annotation is ignored propably because in parent this method doesnt contain this annotation (due to maven dependencies).

Foo is just basic class with this method.

How should I fix thix problem ?

Answer (score 0):

If the `getList()` method exists in the super class `Foo`, then the annotation will be ignored in the subclass, as the `list` property has already been processed as part of the parent class.  You can do one of the following:

1. Move the annotation to the `list` property on the `Foo` class.
2. Annotate the `Foo` class with `@XmlTransient` to remove it from the inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: hm and when I annotate with XmlTransient whole class and Foo contains more variable then FooImpl(here I just override one method) then it still save this object to xml ?

Comment: @hudi - `@XmlTransient` when used on a class is different from when it is used on a field/property.  When used on a class it just removes it from the inheritance hierarchy.  Then all properties from the super class are treated as properties of the subclass:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/ignoring-inheritance-with-xmltransient.html